# MSBuild.exe does not exist

Tags: .net, docker, jenkins

**My Jenkins is running in a Docker container

In Global Tool Configuration I have set the following MSBuild installation**

[image]

**And in the configurations of my job I chose the MSBuild installation and gave the path to the needed sln. file**

[image]

**But when I build the job, I get this**

[image]

**So It is telling me the file does not exist but it obviously does exist.
I am guessing this has something to do with docker maybe.
Could you please help me with this?**

Comment: You probably configured a 32 bit agent so that it cannot read 64 bit file paths.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for the comment. Do you know how I can configure to 64-bit?